# Php mail function won't work

Tags: php, forms, email

After researching several questions and try multiple options, I couldn't make it work still!

I have this contact form that won't be sent.

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="process.php">
    <fieldset>  

        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" title="Your name" class="required">

        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourmail@domain.com" title="Your e-mail address" class="required email">

        <label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="+34 111 22 33 44" title="Your phone number">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="si">
        <span class="destacar-contacto">ACCEPT</span> the invitation<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="no">
        <span class="destacar-contacto">REJECT</span> the invitation<br>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="negrita-contacto">If you're coming: what would you like better?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="menu" value="carne"> Calf sirloin with foie<br>
        <input type="radio" name="menu" value="pescado"> Marinade salmon with dill<br>
        <input type="radio" name="menu" value="vegetariano"> Fungus risotto<br>

        <label for="mas">Is someone coming with you? Let us know their name and their prefered menu here:</label>
        <textarea name="mas"></textarea>

        <label for="message">Aditional message:</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="boton" id="submit" value="Enviar" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this is the PHP function:

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$rsvp = strip_tags($_POST['rsvp']);
$menu = strip_tags($_POST['menu']);
$mas = strip_tags($_POST['mas']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

mail( "formulario@ourdreamjourney.com", "rsvp",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nRsvp: $rsvp\nMenu: $menu\nMas: $mas\nMessage: $message\n",
"From: Our Dream Journey <mail@hotmail.com>" );
```

I tried randomly to send just "Name: $name" and I got an e-mail! But then put all the other options back and nothing again...

Someone can help me please?

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: Are you try only send a mail `mail('formulario@ourdreamjourney.com', 'test', 'message'); ?`

Comment: Spam filter is blocking it. Take a look at the content of the message when it doesn't get received, spammy keywords? Also to debug you should check the return value of `mail()` to see if it was accepted for delivery.

Comment: @MarinSagovac Yes, I tried that and it works so I think it may be an issue with this line: "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nRsvp: $rsvp\nMenu: $menu\nMas: $mas\nMessage: $message\n"

Comment: @MrCode Spam? I don't think so! The form is a RSVP for a wedding, so there are no spammy keywords on that at all. Or I think so!

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpMailer class. Download this library from here. Many example with to send email.

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list

**Edit:**

Try this code

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From:Our Dream Journey <mail@hotmail.com>' . "\r\n";

    if(mail( "formulario@ourdreamjourney.com", "rsvp",nl2br("Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nRsvp: $rsvp\nMenu: $menu\nMas: $mas\nMessage: $message\n"),
    $headers )) echo "Sent"; die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all the information to the header element:

```
$headers = "From: myplace@here.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: myplace2@here.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: myplace@here.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@noplace.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@special.com\r\n";
```

Maybe there also other options that I don't remember like MIME
Maybe another problem is that some of the variables break the string(close the string). Try to print it somewhere,a file with file_put_contents or just echo it